# React Native not rendering value immediately after state update when using moment

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I am trying to have buttons update the currently selected month, however, I am only seeing the changes rendered when the screen is reloaded (i.e hitting save in the IDE). I am not sure if this is related to my use of the moment.js package.

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
[...]

export default function MySchedule() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(moment());

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      [...]
      <View style={styles.calendar}>
        <View style={styles.calendarHeader}>
          <Text style={styles.calendarHeaderText}>
            {selectedDate.format('MMMM')} {selectedDate.year()}
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.calendarButtonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                const newMonth = selectedDate.subtract(1, 'month');
                setSelectedDate(newMonth);
              }}>
              <ChevronLeft color="white" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                const newMonth = selectedDate.add(1, 'month');
                setSelectedDate(newMonth);
              }}
              style={styles.chevronRight}>
              <ChevronRight />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  [...]
});
```

Comment: Does the answer to this question help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804843/react-form-instance-not-inserting-to-list/70805147#70805147

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not the most ideal solution, I was able to work around this bug by having a dummy hook be incremented whenever the selected date is changed:

```js
  const [dummyHook, setDummyHook] = useState(0);
  [...]
   <View style={styles.calendarButtonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            setSelectedDate(oldMonth => oldMonth.subtract(1, 'month'));
            console.log('newMonth', selectedDate);
            setDummyHook(oldDummyHook => oldDummyHook + 1);
          }}>
          <ChevronLeft color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            setSelectedDate(oldMonth => oldMonth.add(1, 'month'));
            console.log('newMonth', selectedDate);
            setDummyHook(oldDummyHook => oldDummyHook + 1);
          }}
          style={styles.chevronRight}>
          <ChevronRight />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```